# Skipping npm install when running npm link

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-link

I already have node_modules installed, and I want to run `npm link`, is there a way to skil npm install phase when running `npm link`, something like:

```
npm link --skip-install
```

or

```
npm link --install=false
```

here at the npm link docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren’t doing anything wrong at all, it is actually `npm link` that is broken. An issue was first officially reported on May 30, 2017 and it has not yet been fixed nor has the issue been closed. It appears that once `npm@7` is released, this issue will be fixed according to member comments about a rewrite. For now you may want to try out `yarn link`.

[image: Official comment]

If you are intrested in learning more, feel free to check out their [blog post about it](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/173239798780/beyond-npm6-the-future-of-the-npm-cli).